# Trigger blur() on editable <span> in safari with React

Tags: javascript, reactjs, safari

I started working with editable  fields using react. I need to trigger blur() event when user push "Enter" while typing into the  field. My code works in Chrome, but it does not work properly in Safari. When I press on  tag text cursor stays on  in Safari  does not trigger.

Function to trigger blur():

```
// Event handler

saveChanges (event) {
    const key = event.key;

    if (key ==='Enter') {
        event.preventDefault();
        event.target.blur();
    }
}
```

JSX:

```
<li>
    <span
        contentEditable
        suppressContentEditableWarning
        onBlur = { this._modifyState}
        onKeyPress = { this._saveChanges }>
        { profile[title] }
    </span>
</li>
<li>
    <select onMouseDown = { (event) => {event.target.focus();} }>
        <option>Option 1</option>
        <option>Option 1</option>
        <option>Option 1</option>                    
    </select>
</li>
```